# Clearing instance of image

Tags: c#, image, dispose

Just not sure, if I have class of type Image and want to clear it, is it enough to set its instance to null?
Or I need to call its dispose method? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely dispose it. For example, it might have an open file handle which will remain in use until finalization if you just allow the image to be garbage collected. That's just one practical example of a problem - but the best clue that you should dispose of the image is that the class implements `IDisposable` :)

Note that usually you *shouldn't* set variables to null - that's rarely required, and adds clutter to the code. You *should* dispose of disposable objects. Typically that's done in a `using` statement, unless you're disposing of an instance variable, which would typically be done within your own `Dispose` method.

Final note: you can't set an *instance* to null... you can assign the value "null" to a variable, that's all.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I thought setting variable pointing to instance to null. I assumed that if the last reference disappead, the object disappear - I have read that.

Comment: @Tray13: No, .NET doesn't use ref counting. An object is eligible for garbage collection when there are no "live" variables referring to it - but that doesn't mean it's collected right away, and there can be other variables still referring to it, so long as those variables are *also* within objects which are eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: and if there are no other variables containing reference to the object? I have just one.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to call its `Dispose` method.** Setting an instance variable to `null` doesn't do anything useful, and you shouldn't ever need to do this in C#.

In general, the rule is that if an object implements the `IDisposable` interface, you should call its `Dispose` method as soon as you are finished with it. This helps to avoid memory leaks for objects that make use of unmanaged resources. The *best* way to do this is wrapping it in a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).